# SQL Oracle - Data transfer between relational and object tables

Tags: sql, oracle, object, transfer, relational

I need solution for data transfer between two tables in Oracle database. Source is relational type and target is object type of table. Here is example:

Source table (existing data):

```
CREATE TABLE "HISTORY" (
  "ID" NUMBER, 
  "ID_PROCESS" NUMBER, 
  "ID_UNIT" NUMBER, 
  "PASS_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "HISTORY_PK" ON "HISTORY" ("ID");
ALTER TABLE "HISTORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "HISTORY_PROCESS_FK1" 
  FOREIGN KEY ("ID_PROCESS") REFERENCES "PROCESS" ("ID");
ALTER TABLE "HISTORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "HISTORY_PROCESS_FK2" 
  FOREIGN KEY ("ID_UNIT") REFERENCES "UNITS" ("ID");
```

Target table (empty):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_history AS OBJECT (
  "ID" NUMBER, 
  "ID_PROCESS" REF t_process, 
  "ID_UNIT" REF t_unit, 
  "PASS_DATE" DATE
);

CREATE TABLE o_history OF t_history (
  "ID" PRIMARY KEY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already created types and object tables for the process and unit values, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO o_history
SELECT t_history(h.id, REF(p), REF(u), h.pass_date)
FROM history h
JOIN o_process p ON p.id_process = h.id_process
JOIN o_unit u ON u.id_unit = h.id_unit;
```

This gets the ID and pass date from the history table, and gets the references from the other tables for the matching values.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53ee9/1).